# Exact Equations - Why is the solution not simply the integral of N?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the following differential equation:

$$M(x,y) + N(x,y)y' = 0$$
And assuming $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial y }\ M(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \ N(x,y) $$

Why is the function $\phi$(x,y) not simply $\int N dy$ ? I've done a few problems and it seems like it works some of the time, but not always.

**My steps**

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x }\ \phi(x,y) = M$

$\phi(x,y) = \int M dx$

Assuming some function $\frac{\partial}{\partial x }\ Q(x,y) = \int M dx$

$\phi (x,y) = Q(x,y) + h(y)$

$\frac{\partial}{\partial y }\ \phi(x,y) = \frac{\partial}{\partial y }\ Q(x,y) + h'(y) = N$

$h'(y) = N - \frac{\partial}{\partial y} \ Q(x,y)$

$h(y) = \int N dy - Q(x,y)$

$\phi(x,y) = Q(x,y) + \int N dy - Q(x,y)$

$\therefore \phi(x,y) = \int N dy = c$

Comment: This fails for a simple counterexample,

Edit: $2x dx + 2y dy = 0$

Comment: How do you define $\phi(x,y)$? I see no $\phi$ anywhere in the original differential equation, so it is something new that was introduced for some reason, but the reason is not stated. At first $M$ and $N$ have parameters $x,y$ (e.g. $M(x,y)$) but later they do not--why? Also, I notice that in one place you write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\phi(x,y) = M$, but later you conclude that $\phi(x,y) = c$ (a constant?), which implies $M=0$, so either $N=0$ or $y$ is constant. I think you should explain more carefully where you are getting each of your functions and formulas.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By the existence and uniqueness theorems we know that there's some solution $\phi(x,y)$. Assume that $\partial/\partial x \phi(x,y) = M(x,y) and \partial/\partial y \phi(x,y) = N(x,y)$, we can re-write the diff eq as:

$$\partial\phi(x,y)/\partial x + \partial\phi(x,y)/\partial y dy/dx = 0$$

Also the parameters should the same the whole time, ie M=M(x,y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should more carefully write
$$
ϕ(x,y)=ϕ(x_0,y)+\int_{x_0}^x M(s,y)ds
$$
to see what the problem is: The integration constant may depend on $y$.

Now one can use the second condition at $x=x_0$
$$
N(x_0,y)=∂_yϕ(x_0,y)\implies ϕ(x_0,y)=ϕ(x_0,y_0)+\int_{y_0}^yN(x_0,t)dt
$$
to find this function of initial values.

---

A more theoretically useful formula integrates along rays from $(x_0,y_0)$,
$$
ϕ(x,y)=ϕ(x_0,y_0)+\int_0^1\Bigl[ M\bigl(x_0+t(x-x_0),y_0+t(y-y_0)\bigr)(x-x_0) + N\bigl(x_0+t(x-x_0),y_0+t(y-y_0)\bigr)(y-y_0)\Bigr]\,dt
$$

Comment: Right, so I used h(y) instead of the usual c. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but you are walking in circles. The reduction should progress, as I wrote, from dimension 2 in $ϕ(x,y)$ to dimension 1 in $h(y)=ϕ(x_0,y)$ to dimension 0 in $ϕ(x_0,y_0)$.